# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data' for binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, nonetype

I was making a binary tree. but whenever at the while loop when comparing the temp.data and variable val I am getting this error:

```
  "tree.py", line 32, in <module>
  tree.insert(30)
  File "tree.py", line 22, in insert
  if temp.data < val:
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I have seen the same issues and tried but not sure what I am doing wrong here. The code for the binary tree is

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.data = val
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

class binaryTree:
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = None

  def insert(self, val):
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = Node(val)
        return
    temp = self.root
    while temp is not None:
        #here I am getting the data
        print(temp.data)

        if (temp.data > val):
            temp = temp.left
        if temp.data < val:
            temp = temp.right
    if temp.data > val:
        temp.left = Node(val)
    else:
        temp.right = Node(val)
tree = binaryTree()
tree.insert(50)
tree.insert(30)
tree.insert(20)
```

Even while printing I am getting data right and type is also good.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if (temp.data > val):
            temp = temp.left
        if temp.data < val:
            temp = temp.right
```

After the first condition succeeds and you set `temp = temp.left`, `temp` is now `None` so `if temp.data < val:` fails. Change the second `if` to `elif`.

Comment: That's true Thanks Buddy

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this error was occurring because you initialize `Node.left` and `Node.right` to `None` and then assign these values to `temp` before assigning real values to them.

But now I think that the `temp` will always be `None` after your `while` loop.

```
    while temp is not None:
        if (temp.data > val):
            temp = temp.left
        if temp.data < val:
            temp = temp.right
<<<< AT THIS POINT, temp will always be None, otherwise the while loop would not have stopped
```

So then `if temp.data > val` tries to access the `data` attribute of `None`, which causes the error. ([There is only a single `None` object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) so writing `temp.data` is equivalent to writing `None.data`).